# Observe text changes and filter list using RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

To observe text changes on EditText -

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(editText)
   .subscribe(e -> log(e.text().toString()));
```

And to filter a list -

```
Observable.from(itemList)
                .filter(item-> item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Item>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Utils.crossfade(mProgressView, recyclerHotelOption);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Item item) {
                        if (mItemListAdapter == null) {
                            List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                            itemList.add(item);
                            mItemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(mActivity, itemList);
                            recyclerHotelOption.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter);
                            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
                            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);                           
                            recyclerHotelOption.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        } else {
                            mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(item);
                            recyclerHotelOption.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

How to combine both to filter fixed list of items?

**Update**

I changed the code based on the answer but it's still not working.

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(mSearchView)
            .map(textViewTextChangeEvent -> textViewTextChangeEvent.toString().toLowerCase())
            .switchMap(s -> Observable.from(items)
                    .filter(item-> item.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Item> items) {
                    mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(items);
                    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
Observable<CharSequence> textChanges = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(editText);
textChanges
    .map(search -> search.toString().toLowerCase())
    .switchMap(search ->
      Observable.from(itemList)
          .filter(item -> item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(search))
          .toList()
    )
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        new Observer<List<Item>>() {
          // ...
        });
```

Comment: Can you look the updated code based on your answer. It is still not working.

Comment: List is not filtering based on text change in `SearchView`.

Comment: What does `mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(items);` do?

Comment: Changes the underlying data inside the adapter.

Comment: Does it call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Edited your answer, UI changes should be done on Schedulers.io() thread.

Comment: Changes are done on a scheduler you pass to `observeOn()`. In this case it's `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.